# How to reference to placeholder properties in XML file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to reference placeholder in a Spring Boot loaded xml file that defines some properties. But have no luck so far. I tried the following in the xml file.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

<rabbit:queue name="${dummy}" durable="true" />
```

I want to have the ${dummy} replaced by a property in the xml file.

Any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

The startup class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource({ "cxf-servlet.xml", "rabbit.xml" })
public class StartUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(StartUp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work (even without the `<context:property-placeholder/>`). How did you launch the app?

Comment: mvn clean spring-boot:run

Comment: I meant, how did you build the context? Show your main() method and config class(es).

Comment: Edited my post and added the code from my startup class

Comment: That's all good, assuming that the application.properties is actually on the classpath. If it doesn't work, the only thing I can think of is maybe the `<rabbit/>` namespace doesn't support placeholders. Does it work in a regular `<bean/>`?